# There is no proper solution available for "utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 21"

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-science-experience, code-analyst

Currently stuck with a .csv file having 10lac rows. I was loading the dataset in a data frame **Python** called rawdata. The file is having ascii codes probably because  of which its shooting the error **'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 21: invalid start byte** 
The solution for this is not properly mentioned anywhere.
enter code here

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sci

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("ISO-8859-1")

import os
print os.getcwd()

os.chdir('D:\DJ\Placement reports\')

setwd()

rawdata=pd.read_csv('D:\DJ\Placement reports\Copy of Placement Reports _ Apr_Mar_May Page 2.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8')

rawdata=pd.read_csv("D:\DJ\Placement reports\Copy of Placement Reports _ Apr_Mar_May Page 1.csv")

rawdata=pd.read_csv("D:\DJ\Pyhton analysis\wagering.csv")

a.encode('utf-8').strip()

x = pd.read_csv("D:\DJ\Placement reports\Test1.csv")

open('D:\DJ\Placement reports\Copy of Placement Reports _ Apr_Mar_May Page 2.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8')

Data Frame :: 
Month   Placement   Placement URL   Type    Campaign    Ad group    Clicks  Impr.   CTR Avg. CPC    Cost
Apr-18  Mobile App: Cric Informer(Dream11,Myteam11 tips & IPL NEWS   ) (Google Play), by BRAJ & GEETA INC   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=manager.attendance.fantasycrickettips Mobile application  Display-Affinity-Keyword-Topics Display_Keywords    52,584  61,07,340   0.86%   ? 1.76  ? 92,484.03
Mar-18  Mobile App: NewsDog - Latest News, Breaking News, Local News (Google Play), by NewsDog Team https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.newsdog   Mobile application  Display-Affinity-Keyword-Topics Audience_Affinity   99,361  58,55,703   1.70%   ? 0.82  ? 81,644.29
Apr-18  Mobile App: Cric Informer(Dream11,Myteam11 tips & IPL NEWS   ) (Google Play), by BRAJ & GEETA INC   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=manager.attendance.fantasycrickettips Mobile application  Display-Custom-Intent-India Custom-Intent   28,106  43,14,179   0.65%   ? 2.85  ? 79,991.28
Apr-18  Mobile App: Cric Informer(Dream11,Myteam11 tips & IPL NEWS   ) (Google Play), by BRAJ & GEETA INC   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=manager.attendance.fantasycrickettips Mobile application  Display-Affinity-Keyword-Topics Audience_Affinity   39,526  39,54,727   1.00%   ? 1.79  ? 70,662.24
Apr-18  us.com  http://us.com   Site    Display-Affinity-Keyword-Topics Audience_Affinity   23,792  60,06,433   0.40%   ? 2.83  ? 67,301.35
Mar-18  Mobile App: GiftMoney (Google Play), by KingToUpper https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.akp151998.giftmoney   Mobile application  Display-Affinity-Keyword-Topics Audience_Affinity   27,012  3,15,541    8.56%   ? 2.47  ? 66,765.34
Apr-18  Mobile App: mCent Browser - Fast and Safe plus Free Data (Google Play), by mCent    https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mcent.browser Mobile application  Display-Affinity-Keyword-Topics Display_Keywords    31,898  56,07,897   0.57%   ? 1.77  ? 56,368.85
Apr-18  Mobile App: Cric Informer(Dream11,Myteam11 tips & IPL NEWS   ) (Google Play), by BRAJ & GEETA INC   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=manager.attendance.fantasycrickettips Mobile application  Display-Affinity-Keyword-Topics Display_Keywords    52,584  61,07,340   0.86%   ? 1.76  ? 92,484.03

I have tried all these steps to solve but failed. Please help providing solutions or links.
PLease convert into CSV format

Comment: The code formatting got lost and the question is now too hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try `a.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')`. This should just drop any invalid bytes.

Comment: a probably the data frame in python. But in this case pyhton is not able to read or load the data. How can I read the file which includes this ascii codes.